# How can I add libsvn-java 1.11 to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, eclipse, svn

I need libsvn-java 1.11 in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
I am trying to access an SVN repository in Eclipse. I found out how to install libsvn-java and point Eclipse at it. But the error I get is something like a plugin requires libsvn-java 1.11 The standard release for 18.04 is 1.9.

I found a web site that tells how to get 1.11. Unfortunately it doesn't work exactly as I expected. This is the page I found:
http://www.neiland.net/blog/article/...04-beyond-1-9/

The problem shows up when I run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Here is the error:

> N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'svn111/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://opensource.wandisco.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

Not sure where to go from here.

---

This is what I find in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/subversion111.list

> deb http://opensource.wandisco.com/ubuntu bionic svn111

---

```
$ dpkg --print-architecture 
amd64
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
```

Comment: Please post (add to your question) the **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/subversion111.list** file.

Comment: Run following command `dpkg --print-architecture && dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` on terminal, paste the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try forcing 64 bit architecture to the repository.

```
sudo sed -ie 's/^deb http/deb [arch=amd64] http/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/subversion111.list
sudo apt-get update
```

You could also drop the 32-bit architecture altogether, but not ideal if you have 32 bit program on your system.

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```